# How do I create line breaks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I am using some code I found on this site and need to know how to insert a line break instead of a comma.

I have tried using `\n` as follows:

```
if(flg>0){
app.alert('There are '+flg+' fields that require a value\n\n'**+ fArr,3**)
}
```

But keep getting a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean a breaking space for HTML? `<br />`...

Comment: Is that your actual code? Cause `'**+ fArr,3**)` is definitely a syntax error. Would be `alert('There are '+flg+' fields that require a value\n\n**' + fArr + ',3**')`. Also, `\n` works fine in an `alert()`

Comment: What are you trying to do with those `**` characters?  (Because they're the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following text: 
"\n" 
on where you want the line break, definitely causes a line break. E.g. onclick="alert('Hi \n How are you?')"

You may be getting a syntax error because how you've entered asterisks. Try wrapping them with quotation marks too?

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is what you require to get a line break and is correct.  Your syntax error occurs because `alert('There are '+flg+' fields that require a value\n\n'**+ fArr,3**)` is not a valid method - unless you have overwritten it, `alert()` is a method that only takes one argument - a `string`.

`'There are '+flg+' fields that require a value\n\n'**+ fArr,3**` is not a valid string.  Try instead `'There are '+flg+' fields that require a value\n\n**'+ fArr+',3**'`.